# CSS - Set Content of Second Element Using ~ to Title of First

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a tooltip system using CSS and a very small amount of JavaScript. So far I have created a structure that goes as follows:

```
<div class="tooltip" title="foo"></div>
<div class="tooltip" title="bar"></div>
<span id="tooltip-span"></span>
```

I have created several CSS styles so that the tooltip span is shown on hover and a little bit of JavaScript moves the tooltip to the correct location depending on the mouse position.

However, I have had trouble attempting to make the tooltip's content correspond to the div being hovered over. I have tried using the following CSS, but to no avail:

```
.tooltip:hover ~ #tooltip-span {
    display: inline;
    content: attr(title);
}
```

Is there any way to make the span element have the content of the title of the div being hovered over using CSS?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure CSS, no. `content: attr(title)` sets the content to the `title` attribute of the **matched** element, which in your case is `#tooltip-span`.

To have that work in the way you want, you'd need to update the title attribute of `<span id="tooltip-span"></span>` using Javascript.